# is there a method to pass the live frames of the camera to a face detector? CameraX MLkit

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm trying to develop an android app using android strudio that detect my face with the live camera. I'm using the CameraX API and I'm following the documentation about facedection https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android
Until now I can't been able to understand how to pass the live frames detected by the camera to the facedetector. Any suggestion?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

You can feed camerax output to mlkit by using the CameraX ImageAnalysis use case. Alternatively, you can also use the CameraXSource library that ML Kit has just published. The sample code is [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/4645ec6011d5373283b31b79a12fd62f48af3c5f/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXSourceDemoActivity.java#L166). This eliminates the boilerplate code for you to set up camerax usecases and creates MLKit Inputs for you internally from the cameraX output. Note that this is still an beta SDK. We are looking forward to your feedback.

In order to use the API, you need to add the following dependency into your app:

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:camera:16.0.0-beta1'